# Zynq Ulstrascale+ RPU Armv7 R5 How can i implement vector multiple load/store operations

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, xilinx, armv7, zynq

I'm trying to execute double precision load and store operations from/to address locations with vector multiple  load/store assembly instructions in real time processor cortex r5 armv7-r edition such as VLDMIA/VSTMIA and LDM/STM . Also i added appropriate compilation flags -mcpu=cortex-r5 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=softfp , however it doesn't work . Does anyone know what should i do ?

```
asm volatile ("VLDMIA.64 %0, {D1,D2}\n"
         : : "r" (data) // data is address
         );

asm volatile ("VSTMIA.64 %0, {D1,D2}\n" // Store 2 double precision numbers
         : :"r" (dst)
         );
```

Comment: What source language?  C or asm?  What exactly doesn't work?  Can you give a [mcve] of what you're trying to do, and a simple plain-C version of what you're trying to speed up?

Comment: asm volatile ("VLDMIA.64 %0, {D1,D2}\n"        
                        :
                        : "r" (data)                                // data is address
                    );

Comment: asm volatile ("VSTMIA.64 %0, {D1,D2}\n"         // Store 2 double precision numbers
                    :
                    :"r" (dst)                    //destination is address
                );

Comment: I 'm trying to load and store 2 double precision words from/to a memory address

Comment: For the store, your constraint needs to be `"=>m"(*dst)` (for the post-increment), because `VSTMIA.64  r0, {D1,D2}` won't assemble.  You also need input constraints for the 2 inputs so gcc knows what to put in D1 and D2, using `register double d1 asm("d1")`.  If write correct constraints, you don't need `volatile`.  Working on an answer.